# List updates in two places

Tags: python

In python you can create a list like so:

```
[[0,0]]*n
```

This creates a list such as this:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

The issue is when you update the list such as:

```
li[0][0]=10
[[10, 0], [10, 0], [10, 0]]
```

Is there anyway to create lists of a certain size with this method but not encountering this problem?

I created this workaround but is there a better way?

```
for x in range(players):
    li+=[[0]*n]
```

Comment: The reason why this happens is because lists are stored by reference - so when you do `[[0,0]]*n`, what that is interpreted as is "make a list `[0,0]`, and then make a second list which is `n` copies of the reference to that first list."

Comment: See note 2. in the online Python documentation on [Sequence Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
li = [[0,0] for i in range(players)]
```